# Combining boot partion from seperate SSDs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, boot-partition

I have 2 SSDs on my computer, the first has Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed alongside it. The dual boot was working correctly.

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a a second SSD, but it created an entire fresh install of Linux including the boot partition and now the computer skips the GRUB menu and boots directly into ubuntu on the second hard drive.

[gparted view of disk1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XssHO.png)

[gparted view of disk2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JahHw.png)

How can I stop this automatic boot and have a GRUB menu that lets me choose between Win11 and both Ubuntu installations? Does this involve removing the boot partition from the second drive?

Edit:

1. The second ubuntu was an OEM installation where I selected the second SSD.
2. If I press F12 I can access the original GRUB menu to select windows, but if I do nothing it boots directly into ubuntu on the second drive.

Comment: Typically the installer doesn't create anew ESP (I suppose that's what you mean by "boot partition"?) and just use the one that already exists. Or, by any chance, you installed the second Ubuntu in Legacy mode?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I added 2 images from gparted. Im not sure if the OEM install acts differently.

Comment: Can you try "sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" in a terminal?

Comment: The Ubiquity installer only installs grub to the first drive's ESP. And last install overwrites any previous entries. But you should be able to boot all installs from new grub menu. You have to edit fstab and reinstall grub if you want separate UEFI entries. Also then best to change one from "ubuntu" so in UEFI you have two unique names, otherwise you have two "ubuntu" entries. Also grub only boots working Windows. And Windows updates often turn fast startup back on, preventing grub from booting Windows. You then have to boot directly from UEFI boot menu.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. @oldfred, that makes sense - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring back the GRUB menu and merge Windows 11 and both Ubuntus into 1 menu, I installed grub customizer via `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`.

Then in `General Settings` I checked off "look for other operating systems" and increased the "boot default entry time after" to anything > 0.

Note: The name of the OS can be changed by right clicking on the entries in the `List Configuration` tab.